# Recharts: how to add minor ticks (ruler-like axis) without labels

Tags: recharts

Trying to get a ruler-like effect, where the numeric ticks are separated by a number of minor ticks, e.g.

0....|....10....|....20

Have looked at adding a second YAxis but can't find an option in the docs https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis to get it to display the tick lines but not the numbers. A tickFormatter that returns null just results in the text 'null' as tick label.

Will also have to change the offset to get both axes to render on top of each other, as default is to offset the second axis. Can't find an option to do this either.

Any way to do this with Recharts? Or is it custom SVG this time?